# PDO: не отрабатывает UPDATE

Tags: php, pdo

Здравствуйте, следующая проблема приключилась.

Есть запрос вида:

```
$prepare4 = $db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `score` = :score WHERE `vkid` = :id");
$prepare4 -> bindParam(":score", $score, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$prepare4 -> bindParam(":id", $_SESSION['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$prepare4 -> execute();
```

Однако когда пытаюсь обработать это дело, в БД ничего не меняется.

errorinfo() выдало:

```
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
```

т.е. вроде как ошибок нет.

var_dump отдал следующее:

> object(PDOStatement)#8 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(60) "UPDATE `users` SET `score` = :score WHERE `id` = :id" }

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: > var_dump отдал следующее:

это эм отличается от оригинальной query

проверьте affected rows, вангую, что там стоит 0

Comment: @Etki, однако Вы не правы - там показало двоечку.

Comment: @Виталий RS, а как вы определили, что данные не обновляются? Affected rows сообщает движок БД, т.е. что-то все-таки обновилось.